# Enabling developer options does not work

Tags: rooting, usb-debugging, developer-options

I have a Samsung J3 (2016) which I would like to root. To do so, I want to enable the developers options. I tried the method which always works (tap 7 times on build number). This method does not work unfortunately.

Is there a different method to get usb debugging enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Family link was the reason developer options could not be enabled. After changing the device settings in Family Link app, developer options could be enabled by tapping 7 times on the build number section.